# How to limit the area of a html text field?

Tags: html, css

I have a text box defined by the following code:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="8" size="8">
```

The problem I am having in the text box stretches all the way to the end of the screen instead of being limited to a specific size on the page. The box is crowding out other screen elements and making horizontal placement difficult as a result.

There are no CSS elements currently defining the box outside of the default attributes

Comment: "*There are no CSS elements currently defining the box outside of the default attributes*" What is a "*CSS [element]*"? Do you mean an HTML element? What "*default attributes*" are you referring to?

Comment: You see, R Engler, by the code you shared and the description you gave us the input field should not have the problem you described. Probably the problem is somewhere else, and we might need more context around the problem in order to understand what's going on.

Comment: apply `width` for the field that how much you want?